# XMLUnit-2 ignore certain nested XML elements

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

My XML is little complex and I've to ignore certain `entry` from the comparison, how would I able to achieve it ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE ResourceObject PUBLIC "my_corp.dtd" "my_corp.dtd">
<ResourceObject displayName="TESTNGAD\AggUserFSP test" identity="CN=AggUserFSP test,OU=FSPAggeFrame,OU=unittests,DC=TestNGAD,DC=local" objectType="account" uuid="{97182a65-61f2-443c-b0fa-477d0821d8c4}">
   <Attributes>
     <Map>
       <entry key="accountFlags">
         <value>
           <List>
             <String>Normal User Account</String>
             <String>Password Cannot Expire</String>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
       <entry key="homePhone" value="6555"/>
       <entry key="l" value="Pune"/>
       <entry key="memberOf">
         <value>
           <List>
             <String>CN=FSPGRP2,OU=ADAggF,OU=unittests2,DC=AUTODOMAIN,DC=LOCAL</String>
             <String>CN=FSPGRP1,OU=ADAggF,OU=unittests2,DC=AUTODOMAIN,DC=LOCAL</String>
             <String>CN=LocalAggFrame,OU=FSPAggeFrame,OU=unittests,DC=TestNGAD,DC=local</String>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
       <entry key="objectClass">
         <value>
           <List>
             <String>top</String>
             <String>person</String>
             <String>organizationalPerson</String>
             <String>user</String>
           </List>
         </value>
       </entry>
       <entry key="sn" value="test"/>
       <entry key="st" value="MH"/>
       <entry key="streetAddress" value="SB ROAD"/>
       <entry key="title" value="QA"/>
       <entry key="userPrincipalName" value="AggUserFSP test@TestNGAD.local"/>
     </Map>
   </Attributes>
 </ResourceObject>
```

I tried

```
Diff diff = DiffBuilder
             .compare(control)
             .withTest(test)
             .checkForSimilar().checkForIdentical()
             .normalizeWhitespace()
             .ignoreComments()
             .ignoreWhitespace()
             .withNodeFilter(node -> !(node.getNodeName().equals("accountFlags") ||
                            node.getNodeName().equals("homePhone"))).build();
```

But, it is not working. How should I ignore some `XML entry` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither "accountFlags" nor "homePhone" are element names, so my filter will not match anything.

The NodeFilter must return true unless all of the following conditions are met

- node is actually an Element
- node has an attribute named "key"
- the value of this attribute is either "accountFralgs" or "homePhone"

```
    private boolean filter(final Node n) {
        if (n instanceof Element) {
            final String attrValue = ((Element) n).getAttibute("key");
            // attrValue is th eempty string if the attribute is missing
            return !("accountFlags".equals(attrValue) || "homePhone".equals(attrValue));
        }
        return true;
    }
```